# Script to set up static ip addresses

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, interface

I am trying to write a script to simply set the network interface to static in the /etc/network/interfaces file however i am getting a number of errors.

This is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -c cat >/etc/network/interfaces << EOF

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.1.28
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
EOF

ip a show enp0s3
```

I understand this is probably wrong, however i am very confused as to why. What i want this to do is open the intefaces file, write to it and then save it. Instead it says permission denied for line 2 and doesnt change the interfaces file. I have altered the permissions of the script to chmod 777 and ran it with sudo and still nothing. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: You may safely omit the broadcast and network lines and you probably also need dns-nameservers. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The real question is this... why are you changing /etc/network/interfaces? If this is a desktop installation, using NetworkManager, why not use the standard NM GUI to set up your static address? And, why would you try and script what would be a one-time edit anyway?

Comment: Honestly @heynnema, your correct. This has no functional purpose, it was just a task set from my lecturers that I was having trouble with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trailing space character in your first line after the `#!`.
Also, remove the `-c` option. It is not a sudo option for entering a command. You may be confused with the su command.

And, beware, unless you want to overwrite all `/etc/network/interfaces` file, you've got to use `>>` instead of a single `>`.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo cat >> /etc/network/interfaces << EOF

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 192.168.1.28
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
EOF
```